# How to call a function in a screen from native Header in react native?

Tags: react-native

This is a screen where function named logNumbers() is located.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const MyScreen = () => {
  const logNumbers= (num1, num2) => {
    // Your function logic here
    console.log(num1);
    console.log(num2);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>My Screen View</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyScreen;
```

This is my stackscreen where I would want to be able to call the logNumbers() from (it is the header component of the same screen)

```
        <HomeStack.Navigator>
            ... other screens in the same stack
            <HomeScreenStack.Screen name="MyScreen" component={MyScreen}
                //this is where the MyScreen component is defined. I am unable to access any of it's functions right from here. It would give me an error logNumbers is undefined or doesn't exist
                options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                    title: "My Screen Header",
                    headerRight: () => (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => logNumbers(num1, num2)}>
                            <Text>Log</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )
                })} />
```

I have updated the second snippet to more reflect on what I am doing. Is there any way to add something like "functions" next to route and navigation to access the component's functions?

Comment: This looks about right, what is the issue?

Comment: They are part of two different screens. I have a stack navigator nested inside a tab navigator. And each stack navigator has stackscreens (multiple screens). The second snippet belongs to one of them.

I have edited the question to explain it more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Use [setOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop#setoptions) to update a header and then interact with it from a screen component. Something like this:

```
const MyScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
...

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => logNumbers(...)}>
          <Text>Log</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);

...
};
```

Comment: This works like a charm. What about performance issues? We have set useEffect to listen for changes on navigation variable. And this would happen only during function mount, right? And better yet, is there no way to pass in the functions to stackscreens so that the code stays separate from the screen?